# Manipulate - why does the axis scale change when I release the slider?

Tags: manipulate

I was playing around with Manipulate to demonstrate simple geometric idea of conic sections and put this little sample together. When i move the slider it moves my plane, which is what I expect. However, when I let go of the slider, the graphics are rescaled. So how I stop that? I have set the `PlotRange` and `AspectRatio`, so I don't understand why the scale is changing.

```
Manipulate[
  plot = Plot3D[n, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
    AspectRatio->1, PlotRange->{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh->False];
  cone = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]},
    PlotRange->{{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, AspectRatio->1];
  Show[{plot, cone}, AspectRatio->1],
  {{n, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 Manipulate[
 plot = Plot3D[n, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, Mesh -> False]; 
 cone = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, BoxRatios -> 1]; 
 Show[{plot, cone}, BoxRatios -> 1], {{n, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Shorter version (that also avoids the constant dynamic updates in the previous version):

```
 Manipulate[Show[Plot3D[n, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1,
 PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, Mesh -> False],
  Graphics3D@{Opacity[0.3], Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]}],
{{n, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

or

```
 Manipulate[ Graphics3D[{LightBlue, 
   Polygon[{{-1, -1, n}, {-1, 1, n}, {1, 1, n}, {1, -1, n}}],
  Opacity[0.3], Cone[{{0, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1}}, 1]},
  PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, BoxRatios -> 1],
 {{n, 0}, -1, 1}]
```

Comment: Excellents. Thanks for help.

Comment: @DavidMcHarg, my pleasure. Welcome to _Mathematica.SE_.

Comment: Never new about Initialization option, thanks for that.

Comment: @Nasser, good point; added simpler/shorter versions that eliminate the need for `Show`.

Answer (score 3):

I updated my example to allow both the plane to be moved up/down and to change the inclination of the plane. I nice little example for conic sections, good for kids to see this stuff in action.

```
Manipulate[plot = Plot3D[ n x+m,{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},
BoxRatios->1,PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},Mesh->False];
cone = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3],Cone[{{0,0,-1},{0,0,1}},1]},
PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}},BoxRatios->1];
Show[{plot,cone},BoxRatios->1],
{{n,0,"Angle"},-1,1},{{m,0,"Intersection"},-1,1}
]
```

[image: Conic sections]

Comment: nice :)) ... +1. (You might consider adding `TrackedSymbols -> {n, m}`to avoid the constant flickering.)

Comment: also for kids to enjoy: [ice cream cones](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15816/125) :)